# How to fix "TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable"? (Solidity 0.8.2)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.8.x

I've switched from Solidity `0.7.2` to `0.8.2`

And the addresses declared as payable (owner) are reporting they are "NOT payable" in the contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract MyContract {
  address payable public owner;

  constructor(address oracleAddress) {
    owner = msg.sender;
    priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(oracleAddress);
  }
```

Results in..

```
TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable
```

Was there a change that in `0.8.2` that causes this? What is the work around?

Comment: i have the same problem, i did whut you said, but iam still getting: ParserError: Expected primary expression. payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance); ^-----^
any suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From `Solidity 0.8.0` you don't need to declare the address as payable explicitly, but when you are transferring an amount to such address.

See your example below in `0.8.x`, adding a function to transfer funds to the owner:

```
contract MyContract {
  address public owner;

  constructor(address oracleAddress) {
      owner = msg.sender;
      priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(oracleAddress);
  }
  
  function transfer() public payable {
      payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
  }
}
```

For further reference, you can check the [breaking changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.2/080-breaking-changes.html#how-to-update-your-code) in Solidity documentation.